# Joining a dimension ID to a fact table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, case

I am currently populating a fact table. I've already populated the dimension tables. I've populated two of the columns in the fact table (`time`, `abandoned`) but I am struggling to populate the third dimension key across, which is the `call type` key. The reason for this is there are many attributes to be calculated to work out the key.

The dimension table is for call work type. It has three columns, these being:

```
 CallWorkTypeID - CallWorkTypeCode - CallWorkTypeName.
```

Example values are

```
 1 - OutAttemp - Outbound Attempt
```

The problem i have is working out the call type name, here is a example code for working out the name for example this selects the outbound attempt calls.

```
SELECT * from outgoing_measure om 
WHERE om.CTICallType_ID = 3
AND om.CTIAgentCallType_ID = 1
AND om.Abandoned  = 1
AND om.AnsTime IS NULL
AND om.CallState IS NULL
```

There are 19 different scenarios like this with the same columns but the values changing for each call type.

Anyone got any ideas? I've thought maybe CASE statements but not sure how the code would work on the join.

Answer (score 0):

CASE statements work great for this if you don't already have a mapping table or a rules table to help you. You don't need to make any join if your dimension members are already put in the dimension table. You can just put them in the case.

```
UPDATE f
set thirddimensionforeignkey = CASE
WHEN (cticalltype = 3 and all that other stuff is true) THEN 1
WHEN (some other stuff is true) THEN 2
WHEN (rest of the stuff is true) THEN 19
--ELSE unknownmember
END
FROM yourfacttable as f
```